# Prove the following function is differentiable using the definition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Be $f$ a real function and be it differentiable. The function
$$g(x, y) = x + f(-y)$$
is differentiable at $(-1, 1)$? Use the definition.

**Attempts**

I need to check that
$$\Bigg|\dfrac{g(x, y) - g(-1, 1) - xg'_x(-1, 1) - yg'_y(-1, 1)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\Bigg| \leq d(x, y)$$

Where $d(x, y)$ is a distance function that goes to zero as $(x, y) \to (0, 0)$ (or perhaps $(x, y) \to (-1, 1)$ here??)

I am having problem though because I don't know how to proceed with $g'_y$. Indeed I got

$$g(-1 ,1) = -1 + f(-1)$$

$$g'_x(-1, 1) = \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{g(-1+h, 1) - g(-1, 1)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{-1+h+f(-1) + 1 - f(-1)}{h} = 1$$

Yet

$$gì_y(-1, 1) = \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{g(-1, 1+h) - g(-1, 1)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{f(1-h) - f(-1)}{h}$$

Which I thought to "call" it as $f'(-1)$
Now I would then get

$$\Bigg|\dfrac{f(-y) - 1 - f(-1) - yf'(-1)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \Bigg|$$

I don't know how to proceed and conclude. I have no explicit expression of $f$, but I know it's differentiable, and I have to refer to the definition of differentiability for this exercise.

Thank you!

**SOME THOUGHTS**

Can I say something like this?

Since I know that $f$ is differentiable, even if $f$ is in one variable, then by definition I should have that at $y = 1$:

$$f(-y) = 1 + f(-1) + yf'(-1) + \epsilon(x, y)$$

Where $\epsilon$ is a sort of remainder that goes like $o(x^2 + y^2)$.

Since that is exactly what I got on the exercise, then I can write

$$\dfrac{-\epsilon(x, y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

And I know that this goes to zero as $(x, y) \to (0, 0)$.

Is that right?

Comment: $\dfrac{-\epsilon(x, y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ is undefined at $(0,0)$.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost Uhm, ok... But still I'm stuck with the resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is
$$g(x, y) = x + f(-y)$$

We go through the definition of a differentiable function: assuming $g(x, y)$ is defined in an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, non empty, and $g(x, y)$ is a real valued function (which is easily verified), then $f(x, y)$ is differentiable at the point $(x_0, y_0)\in \Omega$ if and only if it does exist a linear form $T(h, k)$ such that
$$g(x_0 + h, y_0 + h) = g(x_0, y_0)  + T(h, k) + o(\sqrt{h^2 + k^2})$$

The linear form has an expression which must be linear, by definition itself: $$T(h, k) = \alpha h + \beta k$$ with $\alpha, \beta$ real numbers.

So we have to check if we can write

$$g(x_0 + h, y_0 + h) = g(x_0, y_0)  + \alpha h + \beta k + o(\sqrt{h^2 + k^2})$$

Here $h, k$ are the two increments.

Here $x_0 = -1$, $y_0 = 1$, whence:

$$g(-1 + h, 1 + k) \stackrel{?}{=} g(-1, 1) + \alpha h + \beta k +  \epsilon(\sqrt{h^2 + k^2})$$

Recalling $g = x + f(-y)$, we get

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
g(-1+h, 1+k) & = (-1+h) + f(-1-k) \\
& = -1 + h - \Big(f(-1) - kf'(-1) + o(k)\Big)\\
& = h - 1 + f(-1) - kf'(-1) + o(k) \\
& = \underbrace{-(1 - f(-1))}_{\equiv g(-1, 1)} + h - k f'(-1) + o(k) \\
& = g(-1, 1) + h - kf'(-1) + o(k)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

By matching the definition of differentiable function with what we got:

$$g(-1+h, 1+k) = g(-1, 1) + \underbrace{h}_{ = \alpha h} - \underbrace{k f'(-1)}_{\beta k} + \underbrace{o(k)}_{\equiv o(||h, k||)}$$
that is $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = f'(-1)$.

This concludes.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(h,k) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. One has
\begin{align*} g((-1,1)+(h,k)) = g(h-1,k+1) &=h-1+f(-1-k) \\
& = h-1 +f(-1)-kf'(-1)+o(k) \\
& = g(-1,1)+ h-kf'(-1) + o(||(h,k)||)
\end{align*}

so $g$ is differentiable at the point $(-1,1)$ and one has
$$dg(-1,1) : (h,k) \longmapsto h-kf'(1)$$

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me if what I just wrote on "additional thought" in my question is somehow correct too?